# Kendo UI vs jQuery UI - size and javascript framework

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I've seen comparisons of the two but there's one thing that is not clear to me.

Does the new Kendo product use jQuery or does it use its own framework. The reason I ask is that I am already using jQuery and if I use Kendo will that require me to have yet another framework?

Also how does the size of Kendo compare to jQuery / jQuery UI and if I use Kendo is there a way for me to pick just specific components or do I need to download the whole code / css?

Are there any jQuery UI users out there who are considering or who have made a move to Kendo UI ?

Comment: Hover over the `kendoui` tag: *Kendo UI is a framework for modern HTML UI, by Telerik. It is following the latest HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript standards, it delivers everything needed for client-side, **jQuery-powered** development in one integrated, compact package.*

Comment: I saw "jQuery" powered but then I also saw "javascript framework" in the documentation. What I am wondering is if only part of the product uses jQuery. For example I see the product does not have as many effects as jQuery UI. Maybe I am wrong but I think most effects are jQuery framework effects. So if it uses jQuery then I'd expect the same number of effects.

Answer (score 5):

> Does the new Kendo product use jQuery or does it use its own
>   framework.

Kendo is completely based on jQuery. It has its own components API which is well documented and easy to use.

> Also how does the size of Kendo compare to jQuery / jQuery UI and if I
>   use Kendo is there a way for me to pick just specific components or do
>   I need to download the whole code / css?

I suggest you download the Kendo Trial and you'll find all the answers you are seeking. The download package comprises of individual component js/css files and also combined files. Its your choice what to include.